# Affine point matching in general dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry, image-processing

---

Fix a positive integer $d$ and consider the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $S$ and $T$ finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ of the same size $n$. Under the assumption that $S$ and $T$ are affinely equivalent i.e. there exists an affine transformation $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\alpha(S)=T$; the problem of reconstructing this affine transformation based on the unlabelled sets $S$ and $T$ is called the affine matching problem. A thirty years old [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167865594900817) titled 'Affine matching problem' due to Spinzak and Werman presents an algorithm which does the job with time complexity $O(n^{d-2}\text{log}n)$.

**Question**: Has there been developed a more efficient algorithm where $d$ is not necessarily equal to $2$ or $3$?

I have tried searching on Google scholar prior to asking this question. The search gives me results specific to $d=2$ or $d=3$ and not for the general case. I am not a computational scientist and any help would be appreciated.

**PS**- By unlabelled sets, I mean, for $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$ and $T=\{t_1,\ldots ,t_n\}$, it is not necesarry that $\alpha(s_i)=t_i$, $\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.